# How To Get Error Message From PHPSECLIB $sftp->put

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I am using PHPseclib to transfer a file from a local fileserver to a remote fileserver.  I am able to connect to the server, have 0777 permission on the target file on my local fileserver, but $sftp->put is failing.  Right now it return bool, but is there a way I can extract the actual error message or at least an error code?

I have tried $sftp->error, but that value is null.  I am running PHP5.1 (can't upgrade to latest version b/c it is not actually my server).

---

SOLUTION:

Using $sftp->getSFTPErrors() return an array with sftp errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try `$ssh->getErrors()`, which'll return an error. You could also do `$ssh->getSFTPErrors()`.

Failing that the logs might provide some insight but let's see what the errors get you first.

Comment: Thanks, neubert.  $sftp->getSFTPErrors() worked beautifully.  Incidentally, $ssh->getErrors() returns an empty array.